# Sequence for the Scenarios In a Feature File In Cucumber

Tags: java, testing, cucumber, cucumber-java

We are Using Cucumber runner with `java` and `TestNG`.

Where I have a feature file where all the scenario are is there any way I can make the scenarios run in a predefined order because there are `120+` scenarios and changing them One by one will be impossible.

I also know the scenarios should be independent from each other which they are but we want to run them in a sequence as per their priority.

This is My Feature File Format:

```
Feature:featureName

Scenario : scenario1
{Statements
}

Scenario: scenario2
{statements
}

Scenario :Scenario3
{statements
}
```

I wanna set their priority that is why we need the execution sequence so we can execute it any sequence as per changing priority.

We Have Tried Almost every given order and running method. But there seems no way to accomplish this.

What I need is Simple. Changing the order sequence for the scenarios execution.

Comment: Please share the code what you have tried.

Comment: Its not yet supported. But there is an open pull request that you could help finish. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/pull/2639